# Wait between Function Calls

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python. I want to add wait between two function calls. 
Below is the code snap, but with this code wait is not working. My code goes in to pause as soon as it reaches the first line of uploadFullstackZiptoCDN().

How Can I make sure that I have a pause of 5 minutes between the functions?

```
uploadFullstackZiptoCDN(fsartifactFile,fullStackgroup_ID,fsVersion,sdpIP,cdnIP)
makeRestCalls(ugdmHostIP,ipmessagingHostIP,cdnIP,fsVersion,fsartifactFile,'FullStack')
time.sleep(300)
makeappUpgradeZip(appartifactFile,appgroup_ID,appversion,sdpIP,cdnIP)
uploadZiptoCDN(cdnIP,appartifactFile,appversion)
```

Comment: You say that your code waits inside `uploadFullstackZiptoCDN`. What does this function look like?

Comment: you already are, it get stuck in the first call because it seems to be doing some kind of communication, so until it do not finish it will not continue

Comment: "My code goes in to pause as soon as it reaches the first line of uploadFullstackZiptoCDN()" => then why don't you debug `uploadFullstackZiptoCDN` ???

Comment: "How Can I make sure that I have a pause of 5 minutes between the functions?" => you can't, unless you're using a hard realtime OS. At best you can make sure you have pauses of "at least approximately 5 minutes", using `time.sleep(5 * 60)`. And just to make things clear: this will be the time between when a function __returns__ and when the next is called - not the time "between two function __calls__" .

Answer (score 0):

Code below produces a delay which seems to be well-controlled.
It might likely be adapted to your needs.
Among other differences, it allows for more granularity in the start and stop times than `time.sleep`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
t0 = time.time()
nsecs = 300
while True :
    t1 = time.time()
    if ( (t1 - t0) > nsecs ) :
        break
print( t1 - t0 )
```